# Heroku MERN stack env variables

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, mern

I am planning on deploying a MERN stack app to heroku (followed Traversy Media on youtube) and I was wondering if what is the best practice to hide api keys (google map) in the client side?

I know how to add env variable to the server side of MERN in heroku but is it possible to add env variable to the client side of MERN?

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue where I want to access Heroku env variables in my React app which is in the /client folder.

Comment: @danielblythe Did you figure out the solution!! I am also having the same issue!!

Answer (score 0):

yes you can add **.env** file in the root ...

**remember you dont need to install any npm package , because .env already comes with react js**

**create a .env file and define your variable in it**

**must define .env in the .gitignore file**

**use your .env variables using process.env.VAIRIABLE_NAME**

Answer (score 0):

Just create a .env file in your react app's root folder and you are golden. You can access the env variable using process.env.Var_name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use .env files in the "client" folder in a project with a MERN stack (MongoDB, Express, React, Node.js). .env files allow you to define environment variables for different parts of your application. Dont forget to add .env to .gitignore and after add all variables to heroku dashboard

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).